# GeoServer's RasterZonalStatistics result interpretation

Tags: raster, geoserver, zonal-statistics, wps

I am using GeoServer and the RasterZonalStatistics tool with a land use, single-band raster dataset. In the whole raster, each pixel represents a land use category and is given values between 1 and 333, where each value represents a single category. My goal is to calculate the statistics of each land use for a selected area, which has land use values between 1 and 252.

The problem is that the results I get as a response from the server do not seem correct and to be more specific I am confused about the min and max values of each category. For example, why in each category do not have I the same min and max value (e.g. having category:10, min:10, max:10)? Or, why do not have I the min value as 1 and max value as 252 for every category but instead in some categories I have category:26, min:1, max:45?

This is a more readable format of the server response after parsing the JSON:

- Category 1  Count 864  Max 252  Min 1  Sum 5777  Average 6.686342592592596
- Category 3 Count 3301  Max 252  Min 1  Sum 21842  Average 6.616782793092992
- Category 4  Count 1  Max 4  Min 4  Sum 4  Average 4
- Category 5  Count 4857  Max 45  Min 1  Sum 26971  Average 5.5530162651842785
- Category 6  Count 1790  Max 45  Min 3  Sum 10614  Average 5.929608938547492
- Category 9  Count 94  Max 251  Min 9  Sum 1412  Average 15.021276595744684
- Category 26  Count 132 Max 45  Min 1  Sum 3468  Average 26.272727272727273
- Category 27  Count 494  Max 251  Min 1  Sum 13999  Average 28.338056680161948
- Category 45  Count 512  Max 251  Min 1  Sum 31052  Average 60.6484375
- Category 251  Count 148  Max 252  Min 1  Sum 18453  Average 124.68243243243242
- Category 252  Count 43  Max 252  Min 1  Sum 1414  Average 32.883720930232556

This is the code I used:

````
+'<ows:Identifier>gs:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>' 
+'<wps:DataInputs>'
+'<wps:Input>'
+'<ows:Identifier>data</ows:Identifier>'
+'<wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">'
+'<wps:Body>'
+'<wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">'
+'<ows:Identifier>NEST:LGN2021</ows:Identifier>'
+'<wcs:DomainSubset>'
+'<ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#28992">'
+'<ows:LowerCorner>0.0 300000.0</ows:LowerCorner>'
+'<ows:UpperCorner>280000.0 625000.0</ows:UpperCorner>'
+'</ows:BoundingBox>'
+'</wcs:DomainSubset>'
+'<wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>'
+'</wcs:GetCoverage>'
+'</wps:Body>'
+'</wps:Reference>'
+'</wps:Input>'
+'<wps:Input>'
+' <ows:Identifier>zones</ows:Identifier>'
+'<wps:Data>'
+'<wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[' + geojsonStr +']]></wps:ComplexData>'
+'</wps:Data>'
+'</wps:Input>'
+'<wps:Input>'
+'<ows:Identifier>classification</ows:Identifier>
+'<wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">'
+'<wps:Body>'
+' <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">'
+'<ows:Identifier>NEST:LGN2021</ows:Identifier>'
+'<wcs:DomainSubset>'
+' <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#28992">'
+'<ows:LowerCorner>0.0 300000.0</ows:LowerCorner>'
+'<ows:UpperCorner>280000.0 625000.0</ows:UpperCorner>'
+'</ows:BoundingBox>'
+'</wcs:DomainSubset>'
+'<wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>'
+'</wcs:GetCoverage>'
+'</wps:Body>'
+'</wps:Reference>'
+'</wps:Input>'
+'</wps:DataInputs>'
+'<wps:ResponseForm>'
+'<wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">'
+'<ows:Identifier>statistics</ows:Identifier>'
+'</wps:RawDataOutput>'
+'</wps:ResponseForm>'
+'</wps:Execute>';```
````

Answer (score 0):

The min and max values are for the pixels in that category so you would expect them to be different for each category. Consider, for example, Category 4

```
Category 4 Count 1 Max 4 Min 4 Sum 4 Average 4
```

It has a count of 1 so there is only one pixel in that category and it has a value of 4, so that is the minimum, maximum and average for that group. While category 5 has:

```
Category 5 Count 4857 Max 45 Min 1 Sum 26971 Average 5.5530162651842785
```

So there are 4857 pixels in that group with a range of values from 1 to 45 and an average of 5.55 so most of them are small values with only a few as high as 45.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But, I was wondering, if some pixels belong to the same category/land-use, then shouldn't all of them have the same pixel value? For example, all the pixels that belong in category 5 (lets say 4857 pixels) , should have the value 5 and not other values?

Comment: That would depend on how you constructed the categories.